# what to do to have figure caption follow apa style

Tags: captions

here is a sample of my preambule

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext]{apa7} %
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}
    \usepackage{graphicx,float}
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \usepackage{caption,subcaption}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

    \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\mid}{\mid}

    \usepackage{pdfsync}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!tb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black,line width=1pt,<->] (0,8)node[below left=2pt,black]{$f(x)$} -- (0,0)-- (11,0)node[right=2pt,black]{$x$};
\node[below] at (1,0) {$x_0$};
\node[below] at (3,0) {$x_1$};
\node[below] at (7,0) {$x_2$};
\node[below] at (10,0) {$x_3$};
\draw[black,dashed] (1,0)--(1,6);
\draw[black,dashed] (3,0)--(3,5.2);
\draw[black,dashed] (7,0)--(7,2);
\draw[black,dashed] (10,0)--(10,7);
\path[fill=black] (2,5.5) circle (1.5mm);
\path[fill=black] (4,4) circle (1.5mm);
\path[fill=black] (6,1) circle (1.5mm);
\path[fill=black] (8.9,4.5) circle (1.5mm);
\draw[black,line width=1pt,->] (1,6.1)--(1.9,5.6);
\draw[black,line width=1pt,->] (3,5.3)--(3.9,4.1);
\draw[black,line width=1pt,->] (7,2.1)--(6.1,1.1);
\draw[black,line width=1pt,->] (10,7.1)--(8.99,4.6);
\draw[thin] (0.7,7.5) to [out=-80,in=180] (2,5.5);
\draw[thin] (2,5.5) to [out=0,in=135] (3,5.2);
\draw[thin] (3,5.2) to [out=-45,in=180] (4,4);
\draw[thin] (4,4) to [out=15,in=175] (6,1);
\draw[thin] (6,1) to [out=10,in=252] (7,2);
\draw[thin] (7,2) to [out=70,in=170] (8.9,4.5);
\draw[thin] (8.9,4.5) to [out=25,in=250] (10,6.7);
\draw[thin] (10,6.7) to [out=70,in=200] (11,8.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{method scheme of searching local optimum}\label{h}
\end{figure}


    \end{document}
```

what can i do to the caption like in picture

[image]

Comment: `labelfont={it}` as an option to the `caption` package might help.

Comment: and how about the dot and the caption  follow in the same line

Comment: `labelsep=period`, always with `caption`.